# Excel/VBA count how many words are bold in a string

Tags: vba, excel, count

I am desperately trying from yesterday to count how many words are bold in a cell.

Something like "foo **foo** foo" should give 1, "foo **foo foo**" should give 2.

This is my best attempt, but it returns error or #VALUE:

```
Function CountBold(WorkRng As Range)

Dim Rng As Range
Dim xCount As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Long
Dim arText() As Variant

Rng = WorkRng.Cells(1, 1).Value

arText = Split(Rng.Value, " ")

For i = LBound(arText) To UBound(arText)

 j = InStr(0, Rng.Value, arText(i), 1)

 If j <> 0 Then If Rng.Characters(j, Len(arText(i))).Font.Bold Then xCount = xCount + 1

Next i

CountBold = xCount

End Function
```

Any help is very appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
Francesco

Comment: is it possible to have string like this: "foo f**o**o foo" (middle `o` is bold). If yes, what the answer should be - 0 or 1?

Comment: 0 - I need to count only entire words in bold. (Thankyou in advance)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Function CountBold(WorkRng As Range)

    Dim i, xcount As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(WorkRng)

    If WorkRng.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then
        xcount = xcount + 1
    End If

Next i

CountBold = xcount
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Below function uses regular expressions.

```
Function CountBold(WorkRng As Range) As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim sPattern As String
    Dim oRegExp As Object
    Dim oMatches As Object
    Dim oMatch As Object
    Dim Counter As Long

    Set Rng = WorkRng.Cells(1, 1)

    sPattern = "\w+" 'stands for at least one alphanumeric character or '_' character

    Set oRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With oRegExp
        .Pattern = sPattern
        .Global = True
        Set oMatches = .Execute(Rng)
        For Each oMatch In oMatches
            If Rng.Characters(oMatch.FirstIndex + 1, oMatch.Length).Font.Bold Then Counter = Counter + 1
        Next
    End With

    CountBold = Counter
End Function
```

Comment: doesn't fork for string `"abc **def**     def"` (note there is 4 spaces between first and second def)  - returns 2, but should return 1

Comment: Thank you Kapol! **It works!** I want to give you an 'Up' but my reputation does not allow me .. :) Thankyou again! - To simoco I removed all the double spaces inside my text... But you are right, multiple spaces gives non deterministic behavior..

Comment: If there is a word followed by punctuation (like **home**. ) Kapol, your code does not count it.. :/